# CSS Flexbox: How to go from single-column to two-column layout with alternating elements?

Tags: css, forms, flexbox

I want to display a form with labels and form elements in two columns on wider screens, and in a single column with alternating label/input on smaller screens.

So I need to go from

```
label
input
label
input
```

on small screens to

```
label | label
input | input
```

on larger ones. I'd like to use flexbox, because I need to support IE11 and I think despite its quirks there it would be easier to support than having to implement the new and old grid syntax.

I can achieve this using `:nth-of-type()` (see below), and that's what I'll go for if there isn't any other solution, but I need to know the number of elements that will be present in the form and I'll have to extend the CSS whenever the number of form elements changes in the future.

I could also wrap each label/form element pair in a container and have those side by side, but I'd like to also account for labels and inputs having different heights (see the row with labels 3 + 4), which wouldn't work (it would need something like subgrid to achieve this).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>* {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container label {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container input {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .container label:nth-of-type(1),
  .container label:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .container input:nth-of-type(1),
  .container input:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .container label:nth-of-type(3),
  .container label:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .container input:nth-of-type(3),
  .container input:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .container label:nth-of-type(5),
  .container label:nth-of-type(6) {
    order: 5;
  }
  .container input:nth-of-type(5),
  .container input:nth-of-type(6) {
    order: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>label1</label>
  <input placeholder="input1">
  <label>label2</label>
  <input placeholder="input2">
  <label>label3</label>
  <input placeholder="input3">
  <label>label4<br>lorem ipsum</label>
  <input placeholder="input4">
  <label>label5</label>
  <input placeholder="input5" style="height: 3em">
  <label>label6</label>
  <input placeholder="input6">
</div>
```

Is there a more elegant/dynamic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.field:last-child {
  align-self: flex-start;
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .field {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label>label1</label>
    <input placeholder="input1">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>label2</label>
    <input placeholder="input2">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>label3</label>
    <input placeholder="input3">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>label4<br>lorem ipsum</label>
    <input placeholder="input4">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>label5</label>
    <input placeholder="input5" style="height: 3em">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>label6</label>
    <input placeholder="input6">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work with the different label heights (see label 3 / 4)

Comment: Now it breaks with labels 5 + 6 ;)

Comment: What about now? Or do you want exactly how it appears with your code?

Comment: labels should always be vertically aligned bottom, form elements top, as in my example

Comment: You can handle some case explicitly. See the update

Comment: Looking good for the two-column layout now, but viewing it in full-screen, the one-column layout seems to no longer work

Comment: It was because of the wrong media query implementation. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid can easily do this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  align-items:start;
}

@media (min-width:400px) {
 input:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
   grid-column:1; /* for each two input move the first to the first column, that's it !*/
 }
}

.container>* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container label {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.container input {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>label1</label>
  <input placeholder="input1">
  <label>label2</label>
  <input placeholder="input2">
  <label>label3</label>
  <input placeholder="input3">
  <label>label4<br>lorem ipsum</label>
  <input placeholder="input4">
  <label>label5</label>
  <input placeholder="input5" style="height: 3em">
  <label>label6</label>
  <input placeholder="input6">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! You gotta love CSS Grid! If only I could drop IE11 for this project...

Answer (score 1):

beside `order` and mediaquerie, there is not much choices from your code if you want to stick to the `flex` model.

You may try `:nth-child(n) ~ element` to have less CSS to write.

here is an example , but so much similar to yours that it may not even be an answer :)

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0 10px;/* need a gap in between the cols ? */
}
div > * {
  min-width: 350px;
  width: 40%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 710px) {/* equals twice the min-width + the gap */
  input {
    margin-bottom: auto;/* */
  }
  label {
    order: -1;
    margin-top: auto;/* */
    padding-top: 0.5em;/* margin already used */
  }
  :nth-child(3) ~ label {
    order: 0;
  }
  :nth-child(4) ~ input {
    order: 1;
  }
  :nth-child(7) ~ label {
    order: 2;
  }
  :nth-child(8) ~ input {
    order: 3;
  }
  /* next label selected  will be from  7 + 4 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>label1</label>
  <input placeholder="input1">
  <label>label2</label>
  <input placeholder="input2">
  <label>label3</label>
  <input placeholder="input3">
  <label>label4<br>lorem ipsum</label>
  <input placeholder="input4">
  <label>label5</label>
  <input placeholder="input5" style="height: 3em">
  <label>label6</label>
  <input placeholder="input6">
</div>
```

---

---

edit, here is a column CSS example (about my comment below)

```css
p input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  div {
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><label>label1</label>
    <input placeholder="input1">
  </p>
  <p><label>label2</label>
    <input placeholder="input2">
  </p>
  <p><label>label3</label>
    <input placeholder="input3">
  </p>
  <p><label>label4<br>lorem ipsum</label>
    <input placeholder="input4">
  </p>
  <p><label>label5</label>
    <input placeholder="input5" style="height: 3em">
  </p>
  <p><label>label6</label>
    <input placeholder="input6">
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap labels and inputs separately inside flex divs and use `flex-direction: column` on the main div.
Not sure if it's already clicked in your mind and I am Captain Obvious, but that's what I would do.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work with different label heights (see label 3 + 4)